# npm run build command error

Tags: npm, npm-install, amazon-cognito, npm-scripts

I'm trying to use install Amazon cognito Identity SDK for JavaScript by using NPM and Web-pack. Once it is done, I wanted to build the application bundle using 'npm run build'.

But it displays the following error
'Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.output.path: The provided value "dist" is not an absolute path!'

How can I correct this?

Comment: Please check or provide your webpack configuration file.

Comment: Provide your package.json file where u have written this npm script